# Python Web Scraping With Problems

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I am using requests-HTML and beautiful to scrape a website, below is the code. The weird thing is I can get the text sometimes from the web when using print(soup.get_text()) and I get some random codes when using print(soup) - in the image attached.

```
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())
#print(soup)
```

[The program return this when I tried to look at the soup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2bjx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the site is javascript protected..well try this..it might help

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)

#if you want the whole content you can just do slicing stuff on the response stored in r or rather just do it with bs4

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try the requests, r.text would return nothing and sometimes with a status code 724.